# Should time zone be a user preference in a web-app?

Tags: timezone

I'm working on a web-app that must handle communicating time of particular events to people across many time zones.

There does not seem to be a reliable way to get a time zone from a client machine in a web app.  I realize we can get the offset, but an offset is not a timezone.  (among other things, it does not consider DST for future dates).

Is it common, or suggested to provide timezone as user preference, then render all times in that users time zone.

Comment: Users tend to be more receptive to apps that display user-local time, particularly if server time is not the same as user-local time.

Comment: The alternative for me would not be the server time, rather a time selected by an admin.  Regardless, I agree with you.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help ... and from an admin perspective, there is a discussion at [webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11503/what-is-the-proper-time-zone-to-display-times-for-events-online).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Store all timestamps in UTC, then convert into the user's timezone. You should be able to come up with a list of timezones that include not only the offset from UTC, but whether or not they use DST (and, for that matter, when they switch to/from DST).

**Edit:** Specifically, you're looking for the [tz database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). It will provide pretty much everything you need.